# BigQuery function to extract GA4/Firebase user properties and event parameters

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

Most of my queries selecting raw GA4/Firebase data in BigQuery end up looking like a long list of unnests like

```
SELECT
  (SELECT x.value.string_value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x WHERE x.key='xxx'),
  (SELECT x.value.string_value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x WHERE x.key='yyy'),
  (SELECT x.value.string_value FROM UNNEST(user_properties) x WHERE x.key='zzz'),
  (SELECT x.value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) x WHERE x.key='www'),
  (SELECT x.value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) x WHERE x.key='vvv'),
  (SELECT x.value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) x WHERE x.key='kkk'),
  ...
```

and I'm looking for a more solid way to handle my code.
I thought a good idea would be to store this simple UNNEST in a function that I'd just give the parameter name I want.
However even that is proving challenging.
This is the code I came up with so far

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `prj.ds.ep_unnest_str`(k STRING, arr ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, double_value FLOAT64>>>) AS (
(
  SELECT x.value.string_value FROM UNNEST(arr) x WHERE x.key=k)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `prj.ds.ep_unnest_num`(k STRING, arr ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, double_value FLOAT64>>>) AS (
(
  SELECT
    COALESCE(CAST(x.value.int_value AS NUMERIC), CAST(x.value.float_value AS NUMERIC), CAST(x.value.double_value AS NUMERIC), CAST(x.value.string_value AS NUMERIC))
    FROM UNNEST(arr) x WHERE x.key=k)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `prj.ds.up_unnest_str`(k STRING, arr ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, double_value FLOAT64, set_timestamp_micros INT64>>>) AS (
(
  SELECT x.value.string_value FROM UNNEST(arr) x WHERE x.key=k)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `prj.ds.up_unnest_num`(k STRING, arr ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64, float_value FLOAT64, double_value FLOAT64, set_timestamp_micros INT64>>>) AS (
(
  SELECT
    COALESCE(CAST(x.value.int_value AS NUMERIC), CAST(x.value.float_value AS NUMERIC), CAST(x.value.double_value AS NUMERIC), CAST(x.value.string_value AS NUMERIC))
    FROM UNNEST(arr) x WHERE x.key=k)
);
```

In short, in order to handle 2 nests (event_params, user_properties) whose only difference is the field set_timestamp_micros, and string vs numeric, I had to create 4 functions instead of a single generic one.
Furthermore, invoking these functions has the downside of having to specify yet again if they need to use the event_params or user_properties nest. Like so:

```
`prj.ds.ep_unnest_int`('xxx', event_params);
```

I can accept to have many functions OR the need to specify additional parameters, but not BOTH! Am I encountering a limitation of SQL programming?